# GPU rendering but task manager shows it is barely being used

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

The task manager shows I am barely using my GPU. In the render properties I've selected GPU convert. In the preferences>system I've selected CUDA and my GTX1080 is checked. The drivers on the GPU are up to date as well. Is this working correctly?
[image: task manager]

Comment: Task manager has a few different views for GPU usage.  When rendering you don't see activity on the default one.

Comment: To add on to the previous comment, in task manager, with GPU selected under the performance tab, pick one of the graphs (Ex: 3D or Copy) and click the little arrow at the top next to the name. Change the graph to Cuda - you should see activity then.