# Blender barely using GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, settings

When trying to render anything the CPU gets used a fair bit more than the GPU. I've gone through system preferences and set the GPU as the Cycles render device and set to GPU compute in the scene render options. I have a Ryzen 7 5800x as the CPU and a 6600xt for graphics. I've tried restarting just blender as well as the computer with no change. I even tried experimental feature set and nothing changed.
I imagine if it was a bottle neck in the CPU it would be using more than 65-70%.

This is total GPU usage, I've come across other threads and the 3D is maxed out, but nothing on my card goes above this 30-40% load range. My CPU is trying unalive itself while the GPU is barely getting enough load to hit 55C. This card is a space heater at stock clock and voltage. Easily hits 100c in game, I would expect to see atleast 70-80c if any section of this card was maxed out.

[image]
[image]
[image: Green is CPU and Red is the GPU]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203046/gpu-rendering-but-task-manager-shows-it-is-barely-being-used https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179170/gpu-not-rendering-in-cycles